# A load screen before directing to another link. MVC Razor

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Can I possible make a loading screen after I click a button link and before direct to the link page?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="@Url.Action("PCApplicationRecord","Record")" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
         <span class="fa fa-desktop"></span>
         PC Application
    </a>
</div>
```

so far as what I read in the internet, that loading screen or waiting screen is commonly used for submitting.

Comment: Sure ! you can . I will post this answer ( example ) at a minute.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is basic example for you . so you want to show loading before redirect.

```js
function trytoredirect(){
$('.divLoading').show();
  setTimeout(redirect,3000); 
// show loading in 3 secound before redirect this is example
  }

function redirect() {
    location.href = "https://www.stackoverflow.com";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- loading from fancy box -->
<style>.Panel-Loading-BG{height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;z-index:8010;background:url('data:image/png;base64,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')}#Panel-Loading{background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,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');position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-22px;margin-left:-22px;background-position:0 -108px;opacity:0.8;cursor:pointer;z-index:8060}#Panel-Loading div{width:44px;height:44px;background:url('data:image/gif;base64,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') center center no-repeat}</style><div class="divLoading" style="display:none"><div class="Panel-Loading-BG"></div><div id="Panel-Loading"><div></div></div></div>


<div class="col-md-3">
    <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="trytoredirect()">
         <span class="fa fa-desktop"></span>
         PC Application
    </a>
</div>
```

Credit: *FancyBox loading*

Comment: I'll try this @Toon. And make feedback to you.

Comment: I just feel bad that I can't upvote your answer for now @Toon. Because they require 15 reputation for it. Thanks a lot